# Expectation of conditional probability

Tags: conditional-expectation

In cs229, the problem set1 of 2019 summer, question 2(e):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHKcG.png)

why $p(y^{(i)}=1)$ equal to $E[p(y^{(i)}=1|x^{(i)})]$ ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability mass is an expectation of the indicator variable for the event.  The Law of Total Expectation becomes applicable.  Similarly, the conditional expectation is also a conditional probability.

$$\begin{align}p(y^{(i)}=1) &=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1\{y^{(i)}=1\})\\ &=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathbf 1\{y^{(i)}=1\}\mid x^{(i)}))\\ &=\mathsf E(p(y^{(i)}=1\mid x^{(i)}))\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! And I want to ask for one more question: is $h(x^{(i)})$ and ${1}(y^{(i)}=1}$ independent?

Comment: I am sorry that I don't know how to type the indicator function of $y^{(i)}$ properly...

Comment: @gczday (1) You haven't provided any information on the random variables.  This holds whether they are or are not.  Still, if they are independent you don't need conditioning.  (2) `\mathbf 1\{y^{(i)}=1\}` produces $\mathbf 1\{y^{(i)}=1\}$ .